# Nesuite: Gross Profit Reporting by Business Unit?

Tags: netsuite

Our company has two lines of business - a project side and a pure product side. We want to track each as seperate P&Ls, particularly gross profit. Is there a recommended way to do this in NetSuite? For example, we were thinking of creating two departments, one for Products and on for Projects, but that doesn't really work because POs may contain parts for both sides of the business. Is there an intended mechanism for tracking different business units?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at expense allocation. You can set up allocation templates so that overhead expenses are allocated by department or location.

Other than that if your parts are not some sort of consumable/overhead I'm guessing your purchasing is a little off or your project and product businesses are not that separate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that. We have a 2 pronged business model - some parts customers order themselves and some we order to do projects on customers' behalf. So it's the same parts, hence they are mixed on POs since we batch order with some vendors. We fill in a project on the sales orders if there is one, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pull that through and do any sort of p&l type reporting based on that.

Comment: Line Items and Expense Lines on POs have a department in the schema. If you have a PO with 2 of item X for Dept A and 3 of item X for Dept B the costs should be allocated properly.